Reading from the same file with two `using` statements and two readers
I want to process a sort of "mixed format" file using two different writers (this question is related to my earlier question about how to write such a file: Writing into the same file with two `using` statements and two writers)
My problem is that when I open a file and then create a StreamReader to read it, every other reader I create on the file gets an empty stream and cannot read anything.
The minimum example is as follows. Let's say we have a file containing two lines, the first saying first line and the second saying second line.
Then, writing the following:
using (FileStream file = new(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    List<string> strings = new();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        strings.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        strings.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}

I would expect the list strings to contain the elements "first line" and "second line". Instead, when I run the code, I get the first element "first line", but the second element of strings is null.  I am obviously not understanding something here, but I don't know what.

What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

StreamReader will read a big chunk of the file at a time (otherwise it would have to read character-by-character to find the line endings, which would be horribly inefficient)

As canton7 said, StreamReaders buffer their data; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148452/51685 for the grisly internals.

@500-InternalServerError Like I explained, I want to read a file written using a streamwriter and a GZipStream, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78824865/writing-into-the-same-file-with-two-using-statements-and-two-writers . So, in effect, I want to read the first part of the file which is human-readable text, the feed the rest of the file to GZipStream do decompress.

That question is about writing a file, but your question here is about reading from a file? Those are quite different in this respect.

@canton7 Yes, I want to read the file that was written using that question's insights.

So you're trying to read both with a StreamReader and a GZipStream?

@canton7 I'm sorry, I don't want to be blunt, but I also don't want to keep repeating myself. What part of the sentence "I want to read the first part of the file which is human-readable text, the feed the rest of the file to GZipStream do decompress." is unclear?

Your question has two StreamReaders, and no GZipStream in sight. This matters, e.g. because different types have different buffering behaviour. If you gave non-contradictory information I wouldn't be asking clarifying questions :)

@canton7 My question, as it explains itself, contains what I thought to be a minimal example. The fact that the second reader is a gzipstream is irrelevant here.

You could use BinaryWriter/BinaryReader to mix string and byte data. Then use GZipStream in conjunction with a MemoryStream to interact with the byte data.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I could, but that would make for much messier code than I hoped for :P

If it was irrelevant, I wouldn't be asking :) The crux of this is that newline-delimited text is hard to read like this, because you need to have read the data in order to figure out where the data ends. You'd do much better by having a scheme where you e.g. start by writing an int containing the total length of your text bit of data, then write your binary data. That way when you read, you can first read the 4 bytes containing the text length, then read just that number of bytes from the FileStream (and feed those bytes into a StreamReader), then open the GZipStream.

If you want to use two StreamReaders on the same file, you have to use two FileStreams, and configure both to access the file with FileShare.Read and not only with FileAccess.Read.

(As you can see, you may have a minimal example in your question, but your minimal example is something that it's actually pretty hard to do. So instead we can suggest better alternatives, but that relies on understanding what you're actually trying to do). Also, BinaryWriter uses the scheme I describe, but will length-prefix each individual string.

@Oliver The problem there is figuring out what position the second FileStream should be at, in order to start reading at the start of the gzip data. And that's not easy to find out here.

@canton7 So you suggest more or less to read through the file twice? Once to parse the text and memorize the byte at which binary data starts, the second to parse the binary data?

No. I suggest reading it in one pass. 1) Read the length of the string data. 2) Read the strings (up to that length). 3) Read the gzip data (starting after that length)

@canton7 But I don't, in advance, know the total length of the text bit of data...

Then use just one StreamReader and switch between the needed logic when you find the corresponding position.

You've have to write in two passes, obviously. That's common for serializing data.

@canton7 I don't understand this last comment. I wrote the file in one pass. What do you mean by "You've have to write in two passes, obviously"?

@Oliver StreamReader doesn't give you any way to access the bytes from its internal buffer, I think?

I'm suggesting you change how you write the file. In order to include a length prefix at the start of the string data, saying how long the string data is, obviously you're changing the format of the file, which means you need to change how it's written. If you can assume that the file allows seeking, you can still write it in 1 pass: leave 4 bytes for the string length, then write the strings, then seek back to the start and write the length, then seek to the start of the gzip data and write that

@canton7 I cannot change how I write the file, it's a standard format called NRRD :)

This is, again, why providing full context is important.

@canton7 Providing full context is important, I agree. But please understand that knowing what the context is and what is superfluous is not really possible. I misjudged the problem, of course, but basically, I already got the answer I needed. The answer was in your first comment. So in fact, I provided all the context I needed for the question I had.

Gosh finally the XY problem is untangled. You just want to read an NRRD file. I am not familiar with the format, but now that you say it's NRRD, there are probably better ways of reading it.

@canton7 I have other questions, certainly, but ones I will try to solve on my own first

Sure, but you also took a bunch of people's time trying to help you find ways around your problem (when actually, your real problem was something different)

@canton7 No, all I needed was the piece of information "StreamReader will read a big chunk of the file at a time". I got that piece of information with my original question. My question was in no way something different.

After reading a bit about the NRRD format, it appears that a single blank line will separate the headers (presumably the part you want to read with a stream reader) and the data (presumably the gzip part). So you just read all the bytes, using FileStream, and find this blank line.

For what it's worth, I'd probably approach this by first reading the FileStream to find the two newlines next to each other: that marks the end of the headers section. Now that I know where the headers end I can read that part of the FileStream as text, and the rest of it as binary (seeking around as necessary, or maybe I'd feed the bytes read into a Decoder as I go for efficiency). Also, note that there are quite a few people in here giving up their free time to try and help a stranger on the internet. We're less likely to do that in future if you're rude and/or ungrateful :)

@canton7 That's exactly what I am already doing after your initial comment led me to this! If you make your comment an answer I will also be happy to accept it.

@canton7 I don't see any comment of mine as ungrateful or rude. I don't agree with everything you wrote, but I don't think expressing that disagreement was rude in any part. If it was, I apologize.

StreamReader will read a big chunk of the file at a time (otherwise it would have to read character-by-character to find the line endings, which would be horribly inefficient). You therefore can't rely on it leaving the FileStream's position at any particular point.
OP has clarified that they're reading NRRD-formatted data. This comprises a list of headers, separated from binary data by two newlines:
NRRD000X
<field>: <desc>
<field>: <desc>
# <comment>
...
<field>: <desc>
<key>:=<value>
<key>:=<value>
<key>:=<value>
# <comment>

<data><data><data><data><data><data>...

(This is similar to reading HTTP headers, followed by a body).
The easiest way to read this is probably to scan through the file looking for the two newlines next to each other. Do bear in mind that newlines in NRRD can be both LF and CRLF.
Once you have that position, you can read the first part of the file as text, then seek back to the start of the binary data and read the rest as binary. This is unfortunately going to be a bit wordy, but that's probably unavoidable unfortunately.

Alternatively, something like the following seems to work. This uses a StreamReader to handle the messy business of working out what a newline is (LF vs CRLF etc), but constrains it by giving it a MemoryStream to read, which we only add one byte to at a time.
Since StreamReader.ReadLine returns a line when it reaches the end of the stream (as well as when it reads a newline), we also have to check StreamReader.EndOfStream.
var buffer = new MemoryStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);

byte[] b = new byte[1];
int bufferPosition = 0;
while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = file.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        // We ran out of file data before reaching the end of the headers
        break;
    }

    buffer.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    buffer.Position = bufferPosition;

    reader.DiscardBufferedData();
    string? line = reader.ReadLine();
    if (line != null && !reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        
        // Clear out the MemoryStream. We need to re-append the byte we just read
        buffer.SetLength(0);
        buffer.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

        if (reader.ReadLine() == "")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

Run it online here.

Another approach is to wrap the FileStream in another stream, which artificially limits the number of bytes which can be read. The following example is very incomplete, but does do the job here:
public class ConstrainedStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _baseStream;

    public long ConstrainedLength { get; set; }

    public override bool CanRead => _baseStream.CanRead;
    public override bool CanSeek => _baseStream.CanSeek;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => Math.Min(ConstrainedLength, _baseStream.Length);
    public override long Position
    {
        get => _baseStream.Position;
        set => _baseStream.Position = value;
    }

    public ConstrainedStream(Stream baseStream)
    {
        _baseStream = baseStream;
    }

    public override void Flush() => _baseStream.Flush();

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        long maxLength = Math.Min(Length, ConstrainedLength) - Position;
        return _baseStream.Read(buffer, offset, (int)Math.Min(count, maxLength));
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _baseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value) => _baseStream.SetLength(value);

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}

This lets you write something like this:
var constrainedStream = new ConstrainedStream(file) { ConstrainedLength = 1 };
var reader = new StreamReader(constrainedStream);
long startPosition = 0;
while (true)
{
    constrainedStream.ConstrainedLength++;
    if (constrainedStream.ConstrainedLength > file.Length)
    {
        // Run out of file
        break;
    }

    reader.DiscardBufferedData();
    file.Position = startPosition;

    string? line = reader.ReadLine();
    if (line != null && !reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        startPosition = file.Position - 1;
        if (reader.ReadLine() == "")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

Run it online here.

Reworded -- I was typing too quickly, my bad. Also added another option.
